# Server unable to find JSON files, but finds IMG files in the same Assets folder

Tags: json, angular, http-error

I have built a portfolio site for my first Angular project and now it is ready and I'm getting an error when my Angular project attempts to locate the JSON files, but it can find and generate the image files that are in the same assets folder and I can get the JSON when I run my project locally-

```
main.dad43c6….bundle.js:1 ERROR 
e {headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/socialMedia.json", ok: false, …}
error
:
"<HTML>
↵<HEAD>
↵<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>
↵<BASE href="/error_docs/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></BASE><![endif]-->
↵</HEAD>
↵<BODY>
↵<H1>Not Found</H1>
↵The requested document was not found on this server.
↵<P>
↵<HR>
↵<ADDRESS>
↵Web Server at &#109;&#101;&#103;&#97;&#107;&#121;&#108;&#101;&#56;&#51;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;
↵</ADDRESS>
↵</BODY>
↵</HTML>
headers
:
t {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure response for http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/socialMedia.json: 404 Not Found"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
404
statusText
:
"Not Found"
url
:
"http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/socialMedia.json"
__proto__
:
Object
```

When I did my build I used the terminal command ng build --prod and then uploaded the files from the generated dist folder onto my Windows Plesk Server through GoDaddy. When I look at my assets folder on the Plesk server it shows that all the files are there under assets/json/ . I have several separate JSON files in this same folder. Could that be part of the problem?

I have all my files uploaded to my github at -https://github.com/RyanIndustries8/megakyle83

I have tried everything under the sun to make this work and I'm struggling to find anyone who knows enough about Angular to get an answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message, `http://megakyle83.com/assets/json/socialMedia.json 404 Not Found`. I've browsed your repo and there is no such a file in `assets/json/` directory moreover, there is no `json` directory in the `assets`.

I couldn't find missing **socialMedia.json** file in your entire repo. Ensure that this file exist under path mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just realized my repo is not updating (Fixing now). But the files on my server are different. I'm not pushing my repo to my server right now. My json files are sitting on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue didn't end up being my code, instead it was a setting issue in the Plesk Server. I had to go into the Server Settings and add text/json and */json to the list of usable files. Thank you for looking at this issue.